# Gulp: Accessing Added Vinyl Properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, gulp

**How do I access properties added to the Gulp vinyl file object as I'm piping through streams?**

In case I am asking the wrong question, here's my reasoning.

I am using Gulp 4 and want to extract yaml data from the top of a file using [gulp-front-matter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-front-matter) and further down the stream send it into an html templating package like [pug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-pug). According to the gfm docs...

> "Extract `YAML Front-Matter` header from files, removes it from `contents` and add a new `frontMatter` property to file object."

I learned Gulp uses [Vinyl file objects](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl#optionscontents) of which have a `options.contents` property, and can have any added `options.{custom}` properties. How do I at least access the vinyl file object to eventually pipe the added `frontMatter` property into pug?

My best attempt is this...

```js
return src('file.md')
    .pipe(frontMatter())
    .pipe(gulpPug({ /* vinyl.options.frontMatter */ }));
```

Edit: For now, I am attempting to write my own transform stream that will access the vinyl object custom property and pipe it into [gulp-pug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-pug).

Answer (score 1):

I have done it.

Given the original stream which ended with gulp-front-matter pushing modified vinyl file objects, I was able to access the new yaml properties by tacking on my own transform stream that read the incoming vinyl object. The example I've included is absent of any Gulp 4 task implementation, it works by just running `node index.js`.

```js
const { Transform } = require('stream');
const { src, dest } = require('gulp');
const Vinyl = require('vinyl');
const frontMatter = require('gulp-front-matter');
const streamToArray = require('stream-to-array');    

function fmData() { 
    return (
        new Transform({
            readableObjectMode: true,
            writableObjectMode: true,
            transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
                if (Vinyl.isVinyl(chunk)) {
                    this.push(chunk.frontMatter);
                }
                callback();
            }
        })
    )
}

streamToArray(
    src('file.md')
        .pipe(frontMatter())
        .pipe(fmData())
).then(array => {
    console.log(array);
});
```

Included are the npm `package.json` style dependencies.

```
"dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-front-matter": "^1.3.0",
    "stream-to-array": "^2.3.0",
    "vinyl": "^2.2.0"
  }
```

Truth be told, the vinyl file object is waiting to be read, though doing so requires it done within the stream pipeline. I watched the [2013 talk at MNUG](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QgEuZ52OZtU), read a [free code camp tutorial](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-streams-everything-you-need-to-know-c9141306be93), and reviewed the [node stream documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) to complete this.